# Firebase resize image extension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The official Firebase resize image extension states in the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/storage-resize-images):

> The extension automatically copies the following metadata, if present, from the original image to the resized image(s): Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-Language, Content-Type, and user-provided metadata (a new Firebase storage download token will be generated on the resized image(s) if the original metadata contains a token). Note that you can optionally configure the extension to overwrite the Cache-Control value for the resized image(s).

---

The important part for me is:

> a new Firebase storage download token will be generated on the resized image(s) if the original metadata contains a token

This is a problem. The download token for the resized images is the same for all sizes. But it's a different token than the one from the original file. I want them to have the same download token as the original file.

> Note that you can optionally configure the extension to overwrite the Cache-Control value for the resized images

Can you also overwrite it in a way that it does what I need? So the resized image versions have the same download token as the original file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in way that can keep the old token, However there is a way to keep the old token from the original image upon changing the code of the Image Resize Extension function:

1. Enable > [Resize Images](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images)
2. Go to > [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions) tab, click on the `ext-storage-resize-images-generateResizedImage` and click **Edit** > **Configuration** > **Code**
3. Browse to lib/resize-image.js and search for this snippet and **comment** or **remove** it.

   ```
   if (metadata.metadata.firebaseStorageDownloadTokens) {
      metadata.metadata.firebaseStorageDownloadTokens = uuidv4_1.uuid();
   }
   ```

   *It should look like this*:

   [image]
4. Save and re-deploy the Cloud Function.
5. Make sure to deploy the Cloud Function successfully.

---

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: I know SO doesnt want such comments, but thank you very very much sir! This works perfectly and saved me from a much more difficult work around!